# Shimano Pedals M520

Tags: shimano, pedals

I recently replaced an old pair of Tioga clipless pedals with a new pair of Shimano M520 pedals.  Compared to my old pedals, the Shimano pedals have much more side to side play in them.  Is there an adjustment I can make to reduce this play?

Answer (score 3):

With the cleats of the Shimano SPD MTB style pedals the side float* is +/-3° and system inherent. Nothing else is available. There are however two different types of cleats: One type will only release with a horizontal motion (SH-51), the other also with a vertical movement or combined vertical horizontal movement SH-56).
Bikeradar has a description of the two different types of cleats available from Shimano. You can also check their site.

http://www.bikeradar.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=40012&t=12954872

(*Float being the free movement the cleat has before release.)

Comment: 1. Did you change cleats? 2. M520 is the bottom of the product line; not surprising to find slop in the parts. 3. The answer to the question is no, there is no lateral adjustment.